# optimizing derived-subquery performance pulling distinct records into a group_concat()

Tags: sql, mariadb, query-performance

in this query **https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wi525XMRAff2GHUrBpWAM8/5**

```
select x.`id`, (
  select
    group_concat(d.`content`)
  from (
    select
      docs.`content`
    from
      `docs`
    where
      docs.`x_id` = 1
    group by
      docs.`content`
   ) as `d`
) as `letters`
from `x`
where x.`id` = 1;
```

im supposed to pull the **`x.id`** from **`x table`** and with it the letters from **`docs table`** linked using **`docs.x_id`** once and that why i used a static **`x.id = 1`**

the letters in the **`docs table`** can be duplicated for same **`x_id`** so i wanted to pull it distinctly so i went the route of **scalar query** but can the query get more optimized?

i'm using latest **mariadb** version and gives me **`extra: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort`** unlike the one in the fiddle showing **`extra: Using index condition; Using temporary`**

---

i've also tried using this query **https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wi525XMRAff2GHUrBpWAM8/4**

```
select x.`id`, group_concat(d.`content`) as `letters`
from `x`
inner join (
  select
    d.`x_id`, d.`content`
  from
    `docs` d
  where
    d.`x_id` = 1
  group by
    d.`x_id`, d.`content`
) d ON d.`x_id` = 1
where x.`id` = 1;
```

which gives a better execution plan results for **mysql 8** but on **mariadb (mysql 5.5.5)** it is the same results as the first query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

```
select x.`id`, 
       (select group_concat(distinct d.`content`)
        from docs
        where docs.`x_id` = 1
       ) as `letters`
from `x`
where x.`id` = 1;
```

Comment: when i look at execution plans, is it normal to see `rows: 18` even when i get the distinct value which is actually 7 out of the 18 rows? since the table can have nearly a million record which would give me `rows: 1000000`.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
SELECT  1 AS id,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT content) AS letters
    FROM  docs
    WHERE  x_id = 1
```

However, I suspect you over-simplified the query.  So this simplification may not completely apply.

In any case, try not to think "subquery" as a solution to problems.  Notice how you needed 2 subqueries, but I did it in 0.  And it is probably a lot faster.

For further speedup, change `INDEX(x_id)` to `INDEX(x_id, content)`.

"Using filesort" and "Using temporary" are *not* the end of the world.  In some queries they are absolutely necessary.  Furthermore, "filesort" is usually done in RAM; no disk is injured in the filming of this query.  I think my query *and* `INDEX` avoid them anyway.

Caution:  There is a *default* limit of 1024 on `GROUP_CONCAT`.  See `group_concat_max_len`.